# How can I adjust the cursor size of a Material 3 TextField within a theme in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, material-design

Iam trying to globally set the cursor height of Material Textfield using ThemeData

When using the TextField widget you get accessed to a param "cursorHeight" that let's you change the cursor height.

```
TextField(
  cursorHeight: 15,
);
```

The problem is I want to have this globally and I can't figure out how to do that in ThemeData

I would like to do something like that

```
ThemeData(
  inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
   cursorHeight: 15
)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of the cursor is determined by the `fontSize` of the `TextStyle` applied within the associated `TextField`. By default, this widget utilizes the `titleMedium` attribute of the `TextTheme` as its default style. If you customize the `TextTheme` property and, in particular, the `fontSize` attribute of the `titleMedium` `TextStyle`, the cursor's height will adapt accordingly.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
          // Define any other input decoration properties here
        ),
        textTheme: TextTheme(titleMedium: TextStyle(fontSize: 12))
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To globally set the cursor height of a `TextField` using `ThemeData`, you can create a custom `InputDecorationTheme` and apply it to your app's theme. However, please note that `cursorHeight` is not a direct property of `InputDecorationTheme`. You'll have to set it as a custom property and then handle it in your custom `TextField` widget.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
          // Define any other input decoration properties here
        ),
        textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
          cursorHeight: 15, // Set the cursor height globally
        ),
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Custom Cursor Height Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: MyTextField(), // Use your custom TextField widget
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Custom Cursor Height',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this example, I've set the `cursorHeight` property in `TextSelectionThemeData` within the `ThemeData`. This will affect the cursor height for all `TextField` widgets in your app.

Remember, you'll need to wrap your `TextField` widgets in a `Theme` widget that provides this custom theme data for it to take effect.

Keep in mind that this will affect all `TextField` widgets in your app. If you need to have different cursor heights for different parts of your app, you may need to handle it on a case-by-case basis or use more complex customizations.

I hope this fixed your issue.

Comment: The thing is I am trying to avoid using a custom widget for a Textfield, I want to achieve that using theme